# I can only access the latest instantiated clone. The script only works with the latest instance

Tags: unity, c#, prefabs

I tried to implement a way of attacking. Fire the spear, then retract it. Just like Thor's hammer. But when I fire multiple spears, I can only retract the latest fired one. I don't know what the insight problem is here. Please help. And if there's any better solution to realize this mechanic would be great.

The code on hand for firing

```
public class retractArrow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform cam;
    public Transform launchPoint;
    public Transform playerPos;
    public bool isRetracting;
    public float throwPower;
    public GameObject arrow;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Throw();
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
        {
            isRetracting = true;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.G))
        {
            isRetracting = false;
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (isRetracting)
        {
            RA.instance.Retract(playerPos);
        }
    }

    private void Throw()
    {
        GameObject projectile = Instantiate(arrow, launchPoint.position, cam.rotation);
        Rigidbody rb = projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Vector3 forceDirection = cam.transform.forward;

        RaycastHit hit1;
        Physics.Raycast(cam.position, cam.forward, out hit1, 500f);
        forceDirection = (hit1.point - launchPoint.position).normalized;
        rb.AddForce(forceDirection * throwPower, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```

The code on the spear to retract:

```
public class RA : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public bool isRetracting;
    public float retractPower;
    public static RA instance;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        instance = this;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); 
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    public void Retract(Transform playerPos)
    {
        Vector3 directionTOhand = playerPos.position - transform.position;
        rb.velocity = (directionTOhand.normalized * retractPower);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can only retract the latest spear fired is that you're only referencing the latest instantiated one:

```
public static RA instance;
```

[A static field belongs to the type itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) (here, `RA`) rather than to a specific object (each spear). This means there's one and only one `instance` variable in your `RA` class, regardless of the number of spears instantiated.

Every time you instantiate a spear, `instance` references to it, losing its previous value (i.e. a reference to the second-to-last spear instantiated).

---

Since *your character* is throwing spears, it would be a good idea to also delegate it to manage how many spears are there to be retracted. You can do so by tracking the thrown spears using a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) data structure:

- The last spear to be thrown is the first one to be retracted.
- Destroyed spears can be removed from the stack (they no longer exist).

Implementation of a stack can be whatever you see fits your needs. For example, it could be a [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0) where you always add to the end (when throwing) and remove from the end (when retracting), while removing at any position in case of destroyed spears.

Comment: It worked using a list!!!! you are so great!!! I'm a degree student learning game design now, and I'm working on my final project.  Thank you for your advice! I really learned something from you!